# CMTD Enhanced Related List from Salesforce Labs

Tags: lightning-apps, service-console

I am hoping someone has experience with the app CMTD Enhanced Related Lists. I am trying to use it to show a Case Contact Role related list on a contact page (in lightning).
There is an instruction video that is helpful, but doesn't help with trying to use it for contact roles since they are not actually a full blown object.

Comment: From [this app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYDY4UAP) on AppExchange: _Any issues or questions, please post it here: https://sfdc.co/CMTD_ERL_Community_

Comment: I have added a request there - no response yet. And it looks like sometimes it takes them months to respond.

Comment: Contact Roles on a Case is a full-blown object: [`CaseContactRole`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casecontactrole.htm). SF devs are answering questions in CMDT group, there's even a thread about opportunity contact roles that is identical to your scenario but with a different parent object (Opportunity vs Case)